# extract 2D array from another 2D array represented as a 1D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So if I have a 2D array such as

```
const array = [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
            [1, 8, 3, 6, 5],
            [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
            [1, 8, 3, 6, 5],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
          ];
```

which could for the point of the question be any size, square or not square.

and I want to extract 3x3 arrays out of it, for instance at 1,1 that would be `const sub = [[8, 7, 6], [8, 3, 6], [8, 7, 6]]`. So far so good - I can do this. However I am flattening the 2D array so that its represented as a 1D array (long story as to why), i.e

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

What I'm trying to do is extract the same (or any) 3x3 array out of this but while its represented as a 1D array, so I would then get back `[8, 7, 6, 8, 3, 6, 8, 7, 6]`.

I *almost* got there, however I made an error of only working with arrays that were 9x9 and always extracting 3x3 subsets which mean that my solution only works for that specific case, and the more I stare at my solution, the more I cannot work out what the generic solution would look like.

My solution:

```
const extractSubsetFrom1D = (array, subHeight, subWidth, startRow, startCol) => {
    const kWH = subWidth * subHeight
    const subset = array.slice(((((kWH - 2) * startRow) + startCol) * kWH), ((((kWH - 2) * startRow) + startCol) * kWH) + kWH)
    return subset
}
```

In my case `subHeight` and `subWidth` were always equalling 3 respectively, and as the array itself was always 9x9 I believe I accidentally stumbled on a solution for that specific case as they divide nicely into each other.

To be clear my solution will fail for the `startRow = 1` `startCol = 0` for the provided array (it works for the `startRow = 0` scenario

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat (Array.flat) may or may not be helpful. It can flatten arrays up to a certain point and then stop, but that might not be what you need.

Comment: as an idea: `extractSubset = (arr, { top, left, bottom, right }) => arr.slice(top, bottom).map(row => row.slice(left, right))` and then something like `extractSubset(array, {top: -3, right: 3})` every one of the 4 boundaries is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me how you came to your current implementation, but I can at least tell:

- ✅ You correctly determined the size of the sub grid array to return (`kWH`)
- ❌ You incorrectly assume you can slice out a sub grid as one continuous part of the original 1d array
- The calculation of the first element seems kind-of-right but is actually wrong (probably because of the previous mistake)

### From `(y,x)` to `i`

Let's start from scratch and work our way up to a nice one liner.

In a 2d-array, you can get a cell's value by doing:

```
cellValue = grid2d[y][x]
```

Once you flatten it, you'll need to do:

```
cellValue = grid1d[y * GRID_WIDTH + x]
```

`y * GRID_WIDTH` takes you to the start of the right row, and `+ x` gets you to the right column.

As you can see, you need to know the original grid's size before you can even query a specific cell. That means your extract function would need an argument to pass the original width (or, if the grids are guaranteed to be square, you can do `Math.sqrt(array.length)`.

### A slice per row

Let's use this math to find the indices of a 2x2 sub grid at (1,1) extracted from a 3x3 source grid:

```js
0  1  2
3 [4][5]
6 [7][8]
```

As you can see, the resulting indices are `[4,5,7,8]`. **There is no way to slice these indices out of the source array directly** because we don't want to include the `6`.

Instead, we can use a nested loop to skip the gaps between our rows:

```js
const to1d = (x, y, w) => y * w + x;

const extractSubGrid1D = (grid, gridWidth, x, y, w, h) => {
  const yTop = y;
  const yBottom = y + h
  const xLeft = x;
  const xRight = x + w;
  
  const subgrid = [];
  
  for (let y = yTop; y < yBottom; y += 1) {
    for (let x = xLeft; x < xRight; x += 1) {
      const index = to1d(x, y, gridWidth);
      subgrid.push(grid[index]);
    }
  }

  return subgrid;
}

const originalGrid = [
  0, 1, 2,
  3, 4, 5,
  6, 7, 8
];

console.log(
  extractSubGrid1D(originalGrid, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2)
)
```

Once you get a feel for the logic, feel free to refactor.

### The other way around

To go from a 1d-index to a 2d coordinate, you can do:

```
x = i % w
y = Math.floor(i / w)
```

Applying this logic, you can also fill your sub grid like so:

- Create a new array of the right size
- For each of its indices, determine the original grid's `(x, y)` coordinate
- Transform that coordinate back to an index to query the original grid with

```js
const to1d = (x, y, w) => y * w + x;

const extractSubGrid1D = (grid, gridWidth, x, y, w, h) => Array.from(
  { length: w * h },
  (_, i) => grid[to1d(x + i % w, y + Math.floor(i / w), gridWidth)]
)

const originalGrid = [
  0, 1, 2,
  3, 4, 5,
  6, 7, 8
];

console.log(
  extractSubGrid1D(originalGrid, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2)
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this detailed answer. I think as you wondered in the opening of your response, I expected it to be easier than it was and built on error after error....
Just one question - the two snippets you provide seem to take the same inputs - and therefore are one and the same right? The second is just a very 'tight' version of the first? I.e they both do the same thing from the perspective of the caller of extractSubGrid1D?

Comment: Yes, they’re just two different ways of writing the exact same thing. So it’s up to personal preferences which of the two you prefer